# How to overlay a TMS with a GeoTiff for querying in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, web-mapping, geotiff-tiff, tile-map-service

I'm using OpenLayers to display a set of TMS tiles I have on my webserver. Plain and simple, I was wondering how I would go about overlaying a set of GeoTiff files I have over the tiles so that when I click somewhere on the map, it would give me the information from the tiff files (altitude and such).

Answer (score 1):

May seem a bit clumsy, but the way i see it, i'd build another tms layer containing nicely rendered dem (heightmap) just for display, and at the same time load the dem into perhaps postgis raster. Then, upon request, i'd qiery the database with current position for the dem value

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox raster tile query

https://github.com/mapbox/raster-tile-query
Will let you read RGB VALUES out of your images